# Display image in twig symfony from database

Tags: twig

I am trying to display an image from my database into a twig file but it doesn't work, the image is not displayed. I don't know where is the problem.

The image name is stored as a string in the database.

```
<tr class="">
    <td>{{ boutique.getId() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getNomBoutique() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getNomResponsableBoutique() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getAdresse() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getContact() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getFournisseur() }}</td>
    <td>{{ boutique.getType() }}</td>
    <td><img src="{{ asset('public/images/{{ boutique.getImage()}}') }}" class="img-rounded"/></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">View Order</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">Cancel</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote `{{ asset('public/images/{{ boutique.getImage()}}') }}`.
This won't work, you need to properly concatenate your strings like this:

```
{{ asset('public/images/' ~ boutique.getImage()) }}
```

You can also use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) within double-quoted string if you want:

```
{{ asset("public/images/#{boutique.getImage()}") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' ~ user.avatar) }}" alt="user avatar">
```

symfony 5 webpack encore, my upload folder is in : \public\uploads\avatars